# Is there a downside to cheating at video games?

Tags: persona-5

Late in the game, you are able to buy a video game console that allows you to play video games at home. Even later, you're able to buy a book titled "Game Secrets", which makes all of the video games easier to beat.

However, the game gives you a choice to use the cheats that you learn from the book. If you do, Morgana comments on how it's understandable that you're frustrated. Furthermore, after beating a level using cheats, Morgana also says how it wasn't as exciting since you used cheats.

Is this just flavor text or am I actually being penalized in some way for using cheats?

Comment: Is this the same book as this "Game Oto Izumi"  I keep finding in internet searches? If it is, all it seems to do is make the games easier via a back technique (if this is even the same thing).  Haven't found any sites saying there's a penalty or downside to it.

Comment: @TimmyJim uh, I think so? Looks like that's an incomplete translation of the title of the book I'm talking about

Comment: The site I found it on had to be translated so that's possible.  http://spwiki.net/persona5/wikis/158.html.  [This site](http://lightgungalaxy.com/2017/04/25/persona-5-bookworm-trophy-a-complete-guide-to-reading-every-book/) calls it "Game Secrets" and has a similar description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience with the Gaming Secrets book in Persona 5 I do not believe there is any downside to using your "hidden knowledge" of video game cheats. I was playing the fighting game on my game console and succeeded the first of three parts and got two music notes for guts, I played the game the next day and using the gaming secret to increase the amount of time to do key combinations and still received two music notes. So I assume that using your game secrets does not affect the amount of points you get towards your social ranks.